# Gre Algebra question, the least possible value of $3^x + 3^{-2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

if $x$ is an integer, what's the least possible value of $3^x + 3^{-2}?$

$A.0$

$B.2$

$C. 2\frac{2}{3}$

$D.3$

E.$3\frac{1}{3}$

The way I did was I know both $3^x$ and $3^{-2}$ are positive so there's no way they can add up to $0$, which I can guess that the least possible value is greater than $0$ but it's the least value in the answer choices, which is $2$, and indeed the answer is $2$ as well.

I wonder is there any other safer ways to do this question except guessing.

Comment: If this is meant to be $3^x+3^{-x}$, then it achieve the minimum at $0$, so the answer is B.

Comment: You you know $3^{-2} =\frac 19$ is a constant.  And $3^x$ will be lowest when $x$ is lowest which if $x$ is a negative integer can be as close to $0$ (but never equal to $0$) as we like.  So there is not least possible value. It will be more than $\frac 19$ but as close to $\frac 19$ as we want.  If $x$ must be non-negative it could be $0$ and we have $1\frac 19$ or if it must be positive we can have $x=1$ and have $3\frac 19$.  Every one of those answers are dead wrong.

Comment: Yeah.  I second @ArturoMagidin's thoughts.  If the question is $3^x + 3^{-x}$ then if $x > 0$ then $3^x \ge 3$ and if $x < -1$ then $3^{-x} \ge 3$ but if $x =0$ we get $3^x + 3^{-x} = 1+1 =2$ so that's the minimum.

Answer (score 2):

This question makes no sense.  If $x$ is an integer, we can surely choose $x = 0$ and get $3^0 + 3^{-2} = 1 + \frac{1}{9} < 2$.  That eliminates choices (B) through (E).  But (A) is invalid because we know $3^x > 0$ for all real $x$ and $3^{-2} = 1/9 > 0$.

I have no idea what this question is trying to say.  If $x$ is allowed to be any integer, we can choose $x$ to be an arbitrarily small negative number such that $3^x \to 0$ consequently $3^x + 3^{-2}$ is bounded below by $1/9$ but can never attain this value; i.e., $$\inf_{x \in \mathbb Z} 3^x + 3^{-2} = \frac{1}{9}.$$  If $x$ is required to be a *positive* integer, then the answer is $3 + 1/9 = 28/9$, which is not any of the provided answer choices.  So I cannot find any interpretation of the question that would admit an answer that is one of the possible choices.

Comment: My guess, $3^x+3^{-x}$, and a typo.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Agreed.  What a bizarre typo, though.

Comment: As a typo that's not so weird.  But it is *very* severe.  But as a typo its not so bizarre as it would be as an intentional question.

Comment: @fleablood I was just musing about how one might mistakenly type a $2$ instead of an $x$ on a keyboard (it's the same finger but the sensation is quite different) and how that might be missed upon proofreading.  I'd be more likely to forgive typing a "c" instead of an "x."

Comment: not just the typer in a book.  There are type setters.  And even if the the sensation is different our wires get crossed.  I've made much weirder typos.  If I'm thinking about another problem or what I'm going to type in the next sentence (such as the answer is.... 2).   While typing this reply I typed "problex" instead of "problem" because I was thinking about things being complex.  Typing and associations are weird.